# Python Tkinter GUI: Delete canvas objects defined within function at the click of a button

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, lambda

I am having some trouble with a basic GUI I am trying to create. The goal is to have a button that generates a certain amount of tiles based off of a number in a spin box. I have gotten it to work mostly and clicking the 'generate' button will generate a new number of tiles if the spin box value is changed to a larger number, as expected, however if I change the spin box to a smaller number, the old tile generation can be seen behind the new. I would expect that the `canvas.delete('all')` to take of the previous canvas objects.

I have tried to solve this problem by not redefining the canvas inside of the function which I have a feeling is causing the problem, but then I am not able to redraw the canvas boundaries so the maximum number of tiles that can be generated will be constrained by the initially drawn canvas size. Normally I would think that I could return canvas from the function, but since it is attached to the button through the command functionality and a lambda function, I am not sure how to go about doing that.

```
import tkinter as tk


def generate_start(window, canvas, num_tiles):
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=40*num_tiles, height=40)
    canvas.grid(row=1, columnspan=num_tiles)
    for i in range(num_tiles):
        tile_width = 40
        x1 = i * tile_width
        y1 = 0
        x2 = (i + 1)*tile_width - 1
        y2 = tile_width - 1
        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='blue')


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('GUI')

tk.Label(window, text = "Number of starting tiles:").grid(row=0)
default_start_num = 6
var = tk.IntVar(value=default_start_num)
start_num = tk.Spinbox(window, from_=1, to=100, 
           textvariable=var)
start_num.grid(row=0, column=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=40*default_start_num, height=40)
canvas.grid(row=1, columnspan=default_start_num)

generate_btn = tk.Button(window, text='Generate', 
          command=lambda: generate_start(window, canvas, int(start_num.get())))
generate_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button you are creating a new canvas. Thus, when you call `canvas.delete('all')`, you are deleting them from the old canvas then creating a new canvas.

You need to create the canvas once. That, or delete the old canvas before creating the new canvas.